# How do I quote columns using DBIx::Class

Tags: dbix-class

I'm converting a script from using DBI to DBIx::Class and I'm having trouble figuring
out how to replace quoting as in : $dbh->quote( $var );  I've seen some stuff in the docs
about creating your own functions but that would require me to find out the appropriate 
quoting scheme, which doesn't seem to make sense.

How do I quote a variable, using DBIx::Class so that it's ready to be inserted in to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the underlying DBI handle's quote function by using the following:

```
$schema->storage->dbh->quote(...)
```